# return render doesn't work to retain data after reload

Tags: php, yii2

i want to retain data after submit if the data failed to validate. i use return render file input but this is doesn't work because the data still disappear. This is my code:

in my controller:

```
public function actionCreate() {
   $model = new UserModel();

   try {
       if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
           //save process
       }
       return $this->render('input', [
             'model' => $model,
             'url' => [
                 'back' => '/settings/profile/index'
             ]
       ]);
   } catch(Throwable $th) {
       if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
           $model->validate();

           return $this->render('input', [
                'model' => $model,
                'url' => [
                    'back' => '/settings/profile/index'
                ]
           ]);
       }

       Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $th->getMessage());
       return $this->goBack();
   }

}
```

i still can't understand why the data still disappear after submit(in case validation failed)

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed you're ever getting into your catch block on errors happening? Because flash data will only ever be present in your next request so either of the following is happening:

1. You're never getting into your catch block to set the flash data in the first place.
2. There's an additional request happening when you redirect to the lasted visited page.

Comment: i tried to debug ```throw $th``` and it returned error that match with input validate, then i put flash message before ```return $this->render('input', [``` and pop up error appear, but why data that not validate still missing in form input?